# Unable to position the camera perfectly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

[image][![I used blender's old versions many years ago. In 2.8 UI has been changed. I am at a loss. I am in need to get a rendered image tomorrow, a cars interior picture, I got the .blend file from internet (https://free3d.com) (url will be given below) but unable to render the image with intended perspective (intended one is shown in green in picture).

**Please help me get a nicely rendered image of the required perspective**. It will be very helpful for me. URL of .blend: https://we.tl/t-2b2hcIFG9y ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lRoX.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lRoX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, as it were, to change the crop of the existing perspective you can see, that's a (true) zoom, rather than a track/dolly of the camera, which is what the scroll-wheel gives you.

Select the camera by left-clicking its border in Object Mode, go to its Properties > Data tab, and change its Focal Length setting.

Comment: Hi sir, yes it worked. I know it will sound awkward, but I am unable to render correctly, since I used blender many years ago, can you, if possible render a nicely interior of the car with that perspective provided. I want to use the image in a mobile application UI design. Here the four speakers and the music system is of primary concern with some radiate bordering. So seats needs to be bit transparent. It will be a great help for me.

Comment: I'm afraid I wouldn't describe myself as a photorealistic rendering expert.. I'm mainly interested in NPR..also, whoever works on this with you, it would involve a fair amount of back-and-forth which I could not guarantee to be available for. It's really outside the scope of this site.. try something like the Blender Artists job sections?

Comment: okay, thanks for the information